# Jest test write on textarea input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to write some mock string to a textarea using Jest and then press Enter but it does not work for whatever reason. My code so far:

```
test('Should add a message', () => {
  const element = wrapper.find('textarea');
  element.instance().value = 'abc';
  element.simulate('keypress', { key: 'Enter' });

  const newWrapper = wrapper.find('user');
  expect(newWrapper.length).toBe(1);
});
```

My component:

```
<textarea
  onKeyUp={sendMessage}
  placeholder='Type your message here and press enter to send...'
  cols='30'
  rows='5'
></textarea>
```

Just to be clear the textarea is definitely there as the following test passes:

```
test('Should have a textarea', () => {
  const element = wrapper.find('textarea');
  expect(element.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: Are you using enzyme? How is the wrapper created? `shallow` or `mount`? Have you considered react testing library? I find it a bit easier to test simulating input.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, what you are looking for is `'keyUp'`, not `'keypress'`. And instead of `key`, use `keyCode`. The `keyCode` for `Enter` is `13`.

Like this:

```
element.simulate('keyUp', { keyCode: 13 });
```